# add class to multiple selector after click Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to add class to multiple divs after click on button.
here is my code :

```
 $scope.noneStyle = "noneVisible";
    $scope.bodyCon = "notRotate";
    $scope.addStyle = function () {

        if ($scope.noneStyle === "noneVisible" && $scope.bodyCon ==="notRotate") {
            $scope.noneStyle = "visibleStyle";
            $scope.bodyCon = "rotate";
        }
        else
            $scope.noneStyle = "noneVisible";
            $scope.bodyCon = "notrotate";

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" ng-click="addStyle()">Click</a>

<aside class="rightbar {{noneStyle}} {{visibleStyle}}"></aside>
<div class="container-fluid {{bodyCon}} {{rotate}}"></div>
```

here is the Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/sadeghbayan/dbnb2f9x/

Comment: And what is the problem you are experiencing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason why your solution isn't working, is because the {{noneStyle}} is immediately parsed as text.
You can use ng-class to achieve this.

I've edited your JsFiddle to achieve this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dbnb2f9x/3/

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.noneStyle = false;
    $scope.bodyCon = false;

    //Toggle the styles
    $scope.toggleStyle = function () {
        //If they are true, they will become false 
        //and false will become true
        $scope.bodyCon = !$scope.bodyCon;
        $scope.noneStyle = !$scope.noneStyle;            
    }
});
```

and in the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <a href="#" ng-click="toggleStyle()">Click</a>
    <aside ng-class="{'noneStyle' : noneStyle}"class="rightbar"></aside>
    <div ng-class="{'bodyCon' : bodyCon}" class="container-fluid"></div> 
</div>
```

when the bodyCon $scope variable is true, the class 'bodyCon' will be added to the div because of this rule:

```
ng-class="{'bodyCon' : bodyCon}"
```

You can add mutliple statements:

```
ng-class="{'bodyCon' : bodyCon, 'helloWorldClass' : myVariable == 'helloWorld'}"
```

In above example the class: "helloWorldClass" will be added when $scope.myVariable equals 'helloWorld'

Hope this helps you with your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print scope variables in your markup `visibleStyle` and `rotate` that are not defined in the scope.

You are using these names as strings, not javascript variables. Fix this, and everything should work fine.

Comment: That's not the reason this doesn't work. The console shows a 'failed to load module' error because it didn't initiates a myApp module. It's no problem to have undefined {{variables}} in your HTML, it will just stay emtpy

Comment: Notice he is using `class="rightbar {{noneStyle}} {{visibleStyle}}"` and there is no `visibleStyle` scope variable.

Comment: I know, but that's not the problem, he can just add these if he want. The problem is that the other classes also don't get appended. I don't see any new fiddle?
But nevertheless, I would still recommend ng-class :)

Comment: "I already know that and I fixed this in the fiddle." There's nothing fixed in there :)